# Where is the 'secret' in the daily mission "Think Fast, Act Fast"?

Tags: spaceland

Regarding Tortuga Team's game *Spaceland,* it features “daily missions.” One of them, named "Think fast, act fast" features the laser beam creature as one of the teammates and some of the laser-directing puzzles seen in the main campaign. Anyway, I don’t have a clue where the 'secret' is. I have found all the other 'secrets' in the game!

I even tried…

> bringing the laser creature over to the 'human' side, which is possible by blowing up a barrel at the beginning,

…but that didn't seem to open up any real avenues.

So, where is the 'secret' of 'think fast, act fast'?

Answer (score -1):

This screen grab should be more than enough to reveal the secret

> [image: screen shot]